# Display SVG within img tag on full screen

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to display my **SVG** image within an **img tag** on full screen of the browser. But bottom of the image is truncated so user cannot see it.

Here is my code:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#svgPhoto {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <img id="svgPhoto" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/aa.svg">
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f6shkajk/

Comment: "But button of the image"  where is button ? please post working code or fiddle

Comment: Bottom. My mistake. Here is my fiddle with random svg image.  https://jsfiddle.net/f6shkajk/

Comment: check my answer hope it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add `height:100vh;` to `#svgPhoto`

```css
    html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#svgPhoto {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<img id="svgPhoto" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/aa.svg">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `max-height: 100%;` rule to your CSS. For example try to run the snippet below.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#svgPhoto {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <img id="svgPhoto" src="https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/aa.svg">
</body>
```